# Параллельное исполнение дочерних процессов в Node.js

Tags: node.js

Нужно запустить из консольного Node.js  дочерний процесс, потом заняться своими делами в  родительском процессе и через некоторое время проверить - завершился ли процесс и с каким кодом.

запускаем задачу примерно так

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"     C:\experiment\tau.js
```

код родительского процесса  примерно такой

```
child_process = require('child_process');
var c1 = child_process.fork('./forked.js', ['arg1']).on('close', code => {
          console.error('child closed with ' + code.toString());
        }).on('exit', code => {
          console.error('child exited with ' + code.toString());
        });

// тут имитируем бурную деятельность, которая гарантировано  закончится позже дочернего просесса
for( var i =0 ; i <20; ++i ) {
var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1400); // ждем 1400мс
    while(waitTill > new Date()){}
    console.log( "[parent]:");
}
console.log( "==================================");
```

Код дочернего скрипта  ниже

```
var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
for( var i =0 ; i <10; ++i ) {
var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000);
    while(waitTill > new Date()){}
    console.log( "["+ process.pid.toString()+"]:" +myArgs[0].toString());
}
process.exit(3);
```

Ожидалось, что по завершении дочернего процесса сработает эвент и  мы увидем сначала 'child exited with 3' , а потом завершение цикла родительского процесса и '=====================' .  На деле  получаем это:

```
[8888]:arg1
[8888]:arg1
[parent]:
[8888]:arg1
[parent]:
[8888]:arg1
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
[parent]:
===============================================
child exited with  3
child closed with  3
```

То есть сначала заканчивается  дочерний процесс,  потом цикл в родительском процессе , а потом  отрабатывают эвенты  дочернего процесса. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Это потому что имитация бурной деятельности в родительском процессе полностью занимает поток выполнения, и никакие обработчики событий туда вклинится не могут.

Comment: Прекрасно, делать-то что?

Comment: Ну, если логика не подразумевает возможности пауз в этой самой бурной деятельности, то ничего не сделать.

Comment: Ну например в похожих ситуациях, чтобы обработать виндовые сообщения в Visual Basic-е   можно было вызывать DoEvents() ;  В  Node.js есть специальный вызов для прокачки евентов ?

Comment: Ну, Вы же знаете, что JS - однопоточный? И про то, как там работает Event Loop? Так-то можете разбавить код хотя бы чем-нибудь таким: `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0))` (понятно, что функция, в которой это происходит, должна быть объявлена как `async`).

Comment: Вот за это спасибо. А js я не знаю от слова совсем. Учу на ходу.  Просто в процессе портирования приперло запустить на node.js  нехилый кусок кода из другой js энжины...